# MySQL Database: finding maximum within each category

Tags: mysql, database

This is for MySQL!
There is a database with the schema:

> A(**item_id**, category, name) &
>   B(**item_id**, person, length, price)

The question is to find the maximum price within each category of items with length <= 4.
If the item is not in B, but is in A, just display the maximum price as "Null". List the item_id, category, maximum price.

I've attempted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.item_id, category, IFNULL(MAX(B.price), NULL)
FROM A, B
WHERE B.length >= 4
GROUP BY A.item_id
```

The results I get are the correct item_id's with length >=4, but for all the different item_id's I get the maximum value of all item_id's (whereas I want to find individual maximum prices of each category). How do I fix this?

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: *with length <= 4* contradicts with *`WHERE B.length >= 4`*...

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the join condition on your two tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.item_id, category, IFNULL(MAX(B.price), NULL)
FROM B
left join A on A.item_id = B.item_id -- defining the specific left join to include null results
WHERE B.length >= 4
GROUP BY A.item_id
```

Comment: *If the item is not in B, but is in A, just display the maximum price as "Null".* - your query will skip such items.

Comment: Your query will show records present in B and absent or present in A, whereas OP needs backward.